# WARNING: unable to start the KWIC service on windows 10

Tags: windows, services

I've been trying to install the KWIC service on windows 10 from the [official Kaazing site](https://kaazing.com/download/#kwic). I'm trying to install version 5.9.25 following these steps:

1. Download the .zip from website.
2. Extract .zip in folder.
3. Open cmd in administrator mode and navigate to the folder.
4. Excute the kwic.setup.exe --service command to install the service.

But I keep on getting this output:

```
C:\Program Files\kwic-5.9.25>kwic.setup.exe --service
Running in service installer mode
Inside serviceOnly ...
KWIC service not installed ...
Calling installDaemon() ...
Installing the KWIC service ...
Windows:svcutilPath: C:\Program Files\kwic-5.9.25\ext\bin\kwic.service.exe
WARNING: unable to install the KWIC service
Press RETURN to continue
Starting the KWIC service ...
Windows:svcutilPath: C:\Program Files\kwic-5.9.25\ext\bin\kwic.service.exe
WARNING: unable to start the KWIC service
Press RETURN to continue
KWIC service installed
Press RETURN to continue
KWIC installed as a Service.
```

Even though the output says that the service is installed, I navigate to the service console and the service is not there.

I also tried looking for the service running the command:

```
C:\Program Files\kwic-5.9.25>sc interrogate "KWIC service"
[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

And it confirms that the service is not installed.

Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated, as I'm very stuck and can't come up with any alternatives to get the service to work.

Comment: It’s probably named something other than “KWIC service” is the service listed in the list of services?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/kaazing/gateway/issues/929) suggested to delete **SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\KWICService**

Comment: Do you know what are the steps to follow in order to delete that registry? I'm kind of new in this. Thank you very much

Comment: Use the registry editor to delete the key after you export it to a text file.